# 'mvn test' is not execute code with External imported Jar

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, extends

I am executing **testng.xml** through maven test from **command prompt**.

It is working fine with single class calling, without extending any other class. But When call it by defining the extended class, it doesn't execute anything. A build is successful but there is nothing executed.
[image: Build]

**Sample Code:**

```
public class testdemo02 extends demo01 {

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeDemo()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Demo");
    }   

    @Test
    public void testDemo()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");    
        driver.close();
    }   
}
```

**POM.XML:-**

```
       <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

**TestNG.XML:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="other.testdemo02"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Command:-**

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles="./Run XML Scripts/testng.xml"
```

Anything need to improve for **maven-surefire-plugin** ? Without extending class, its working.

Comment: can you share testng.xml file ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes, Added.

Comment: Why do you need `testng.xml` suite file? Just remove it and remove the configuration of it...Apart from that name the files `Test*.java` or `*Test.java` and follow the conventions....

Comment: @khmarbaise this is just sample block of execution, which is prerequisite, For the project there are more than 5 classes are calling from .xml suite file.

Comment: The test will be executed automatically...usually you don't need a suite file...

Comment: If you want to execute particular tests you can give `mvn -Dtests=ABC` etc. see the [docs of surefire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test)

Comment: I am still not clear if `<suiteXmlFile>` tag contains **${suiteXmlFile}** why do you need **-Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles="./Run XML Scripts/testng.xml"**. Are you having multiple `testng.xml`?

Comment: @DebanjanB Yes,There are multiple .xml files. testng.xml is sample file. It is located under folder Run XML Scripts.

Comment: Strictly your master `testng.xml` should be referred in _pom.xml_ and should be always placed in `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that, It was issue when we have external library to be imported in Maven project.

I have comment external library and its usage. So everything works as expected.